# Python Reccursion and improvement

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that allows the user to input the number of children and the program figures out how many buses it needs (different sized buses) and which combination is the best but I'm struggling on the improvement part after you get the original amount of buses. I can't seem to use the leftover children in the function again.

Code so far:

```
children = int(input('Enter number of children: ')

bus1 = 10
cost1 = 100
bus2 = 30
cost2 = 200
bus3 = 60
cost3 = 300

val1 = 0
left1 = 0
val2 = 0
left2 = 0
val3 = 0
left3 = 0


#buses needed
def getValues(children, left1 , left2 , left3):
    val1 = children//bus1
    left1 = children % bus1
    val2 = children//bus2
    left2 = children % bus2
    val3 = children//bus3
    left3 = children % bus3

    print(val1 , 'buses with ' , left1 ,  ' left\n',  val2 , ' buses with ' , left2 , ' left\n', val3 ,'buses with ', left3, 'left\n')

if left1 > 0:

     children = left1

    left1 -= children

    getValues(children , left1 , left2 , left3)

else:

    solution1 = (val1 , 'buses with ' , left1 ,  ' left\n')



if left2 > 0:

    children = left2

    left2 -= children

    getValues(children, left1 , left2 , left3)

else:

    solution2 = (val2 , 'buses with ' , left2 ,  ' left\n')

    if __name__ == '__main__':

    getValues(children , left1 , left2 , left3)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Firstly, how do I plug in the cost of each bus and get the cheapest combination of buses to fit all the children

Comment: I am currently not sure how to even get a combination that can hold all the children. For example if I had 45 children would I take 5 small, 2 big or 1 extra big.